# Wagtail 5.1 - Hidding promote tab will stop any user from editing a page

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I currently have a wagtail 5.1 project where there's a need to hide the promote tab.

I'm hiding the tab like this:

```
from wagtail.admin.panels import (
    TabbedInterface, 
    ObjectList,
    ...
)

...

edit_handler = TabbedInterface([
    ObjectList(content_panels, heading='Content'),
    ObjectList(Page.promote_panels, heading='Promote', permission="superuser"),
])
```

The problem is that, any user besides the wagtail admin cannot save the edited page.
A normal user with the group `Moderator` or `Editor` (or both) although he is not able to see the tab (what I want) he is not able to save the page because of the required slug in that tab.

[image]

Is there any workaround or am I stuck with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to find an answer to this.

At the end of the CustomClassPage add this:

```
CustomClassPage._meta.get_field("slug").blank = True
```

Example:

```
...

class CustomClassPage(Page):
    
    ...

    edit_handler = TabbedInterface([
        ObjectList(content_panels, heading='Content'),
        ObjectList(Page.promote_panels, heading='Promote', permission="superuser"),
    ])

CustomClassPage._meta.get_field("slug").blank = True
```

After doing this and testing with a normal user he was able to edit and save the page.
[image]